# Trim spaces, CR, LF from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried almost everything to remove some unnecessary characters from sql string but it's not working:

```
declare @string as char(20)='  my '
select @string as OriginalString
select len(Replace((@string),CHAR(10),''))as StrLen1;
SELECT len(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), '')) as StrLen2
```

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdOel.png)

Need a way to get this done.

Comment: In the code you posted you don't have any char(10) or char(13) so of course nothing is going to change there.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: `Select RTRIM(LTRIM(@string))`

Comment: CR and LF characters are created when you push the Enter button, not the Spacebar. So replacing them in this text `my` won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Of the three types of whitespace you seem to mention, space, newline, and carriage return, your `@string` only has spaces.  But you never actually remove space.  If you want to remove all three of these types of whitespace, you can try the following:

```
SELECT
    LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), ' ', '')) AS StrLen2
```

The output from the above query is 2, since after removing the whitespace we are left with the string `'my'`.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @newline char(2)  
set @newline= char(13)+char(10)   --  CR + LF

update **Your Table Here** 

-- ItemCode is column Name,Find and replace values CRLF = ''
Set ItemCode=REPLACE(ItemCode,@newline,'')   
where RIGHT(ItemCode,2) = @newline   -- Maybe no need
```

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later

```
declare @string as char(20)='  my ';
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(9) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(32) FROM @string); --Tab, Line Break, Carriage Return, White Space
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to trim all spaces try this :

```
Select RTRIM(LTRIM(@string))
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UHC75764)

Comment: You'll need char(10) and char(13) as well

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get rid of spaces:

```
declare @string as char(20)='  my '
select LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
```

Comment: You'll need char(10) and char(13) as well